# Why can't I insert MathType Equation on Pages 2013?

Tags: macos, pages

As you can see, I can't insert MathType Equation on Pages 2013, why? Is this not a built in feature?

[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed MathType?  It has never been included with Pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This support question](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23517181#23517181) from the Apple Support Community might help.

> 1. Install MathType ([here](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathType_mac/))
> 2. Open MathType
> 3. Open Pages

Maybe Apple is fixing this in the future.